# Is there a difference between 가지고 오다/가다 and 가져가다/가져오다?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

As far as I am aware, these forms all mean take/bring (depending on the [frame of reference](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/1/reference-frame-for-come-and-go)).

Is there any difference in meaning or usage between *가지고 오다/가다* and *가져가다/가져오다*? Or are they entirely interchangeable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The verb '가지다' conjugates to '가지어-' which can be contracted to '가져'.
'가지고' is a contracted form of '가지다' + '고' (and), connecting two verbs.

They are two different ways to connect the two verbs '가지다' and '오다'. Both are commonly used, and I believe they are entirely interchangeable.

- '가지고 와' = '갖고 와' = '가져와'
- '가지고 가' = '갖고 가' = '가져가'

Answer (score 1):

It's similar thing like '안녕히 가세요.', '안녕히 오세요'.

가다 = go
오다 = come

가져 consists of '갖다'+'아/어'
or 가지고 consists of '갖다'+'고'

'아/어' and '고' are used to have two verbs.

가져 오다 = bring
가져 가다 = take out

[this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hAOi30i0UtQ) may be helpful.